# How to solve for positive relatively prime numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

When finding the relative prime for large numbers like 360 (that has a prime factorization with multiples of the same prime factor), how would it be solved?

ie. How many numbers between 1 and 360 are relatively prime to 360?

I would think either

- N = 360 [prime factorization: 2, 2, 2, 5, 9]
- $N(A_1) = \frac{360}{2}$
- $N(A_2) = \frac{360}{5}$
- $N(A_3) = \frac{360}{9}$
- $N(A_1 \cup A_2) = ...$
- $N(A_1 \cup A_3) = ...$
- $N(A_2 \cup A_3) = ...$

...

or

- N = 360 [prime factorization: 2, 2, 2, 5, 9]
- $N(A_1) = \frac{360}{2}$
- $N(A_2) = \frac{360}{2}$
- $N(A_3) = \frac{360}{2}$
- $N(A_4) = \frac{360}{5}$
- $N(A_5) = \frac{360}{9}$
- $N(A_1 \cup A_2) = ...$

...

Comment: How many natural number less than $n$ that  are relatively prime to $n$  = $\phi(n)$.  $\phi(n)$ is called Euler's totient function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function ). Read the section on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler's_totient_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What primes do you need to worry about? The primes that divide $360$ are $2,3,5$, so you  really want to find those numbers which are not divisible by $2, 3$, or $5$.

Now

- $360/2 = 180$ numbers up to $360$ are divisible by $2$.
- $360/3 = 120$ numbers up to $360$ are divisible by $3$.
- $360/5 = 72$ numbers up to $360$ are divisible by $5$.

*But some numbers are divisible by both $2$ and $3$, or by $3$ and $5$, or $2$ and $5$*. So we've overcounted. (This is an inclusion-exclusion argument in progress).

- There are $360/6 = 60$ divisible by $2$ and $3$.
- There are $360/15 = 24$ divisible by $3$ and $5$.
- There are $360/10 = 36$ divisible by $2$ and $5$.

*But we've overcounted how much we've overcounted! There are also numbers divisible by $2$, $3$, and $5$*.

- There are $360/(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5) =12$ numbers up to $360$ that are divisible by $2\cdot3\cdot5 = 30$.

Thus in total there will be

$$ 360 - (180 + 120 + 72 - (60 + 24 + 36 - (12))) = 96.$$

---

In fact, this is one way of understanding the expression for $\varphi(n)$ given by
$$ \varphi(n) = n\prod_{p \mid n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right),$$
which encodes this inclusion-exclusion argument within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $$\phi(n)=\#\{m\in\mathbb{N}:\text{gcd}(m,n)=1,1\leq m\leq n\}$$ 
is multiplicative. That is, if $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ are relatively prime, then $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n).$ Using this you only have to solve the problem for prime powers, and everything else comes by multiplication. It's not hard to show $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1},$ which allows us to compute $$\phi(360)=\phi(2^3\cdot5\cdot3^2)=(8-4)(5-1)(9-3)=96.$$

The function $\phi$ is actually very famous, and is known as the Totient function, or Euler's Totient function.

Comment: Would you be able to explain this in a set theory/simpler way? Sadly, we just started this chapter on it.

Comment: @Math Newbie Can you clarify which parts you are having trouble understanding? I can explain.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I would have no idea where to start with this solution. Thank you so much for answer though -- I get it now!